# Regex to match a range number of digits from a string representin an integer number?

Tags: python, regex

I want matched only the strings that represent numbers between `0...9999`

```
import re
NUMERIC  = re.compile("\d{,4}")
NUMERIC.match("324234")
nr =NUMERIC.match("324234")
nr.group(0)
```

Tried the above but it matches the first 4 digits from the string, even if the string has 5 digits.

Regex to match the numbers that have between 1 and 4 digits from this string represention of an integer number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchors do the trick of not matching too much:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile("^\d{1,4}$")
>>> pattern.match("0").group()
'0'
>>> pattern.match("42").group()
'42'
>>> pattern.match("777").group()
'777'
>>> pattern.match("2012").group()
'2012'
>>> pattern.match("65535").group()
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Note the `{1,4}` -- I'm assuming you don't want to match the empty string. However, this will **not** match `00001`, which certainly is in range.

A more robust alternative to regular expressions is to leverage Python's built-in integer parsing:

```
def parse_4digit_number(s):
    i = int(s)
    if 0 <= i <= 9999:
        return i
    else:
        raise ValueError("{0} is out of range".format(i))
```

Comment: it still matches `0001` See Jan Strube's comment

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: saw that comment. Is `0001` a problem? It's in range, isn't it?

Comment: is not a problem, as far as I can see it, i guess 0 before doesn't matter but is not usual

Comment: @larsmans: Thank you for the "pattern.match().group()" idiom.  That makes testing regexes much easier on the command-line.  +1

Answer (score 2):

^ is start of line
$ is end of line

You likely want words... not whole lines... so

```
\< = start of word 
\> = end of word
\b is word boundry...
```

\< and > aren't supported in many languages...

so

```
\b(\d{1,4})\b
```

however that will match 22.33 as two separate matches.

You could avoid that by doing something like this.

```
(?:^|\s)(\d{1,4})(?:\s|$)
```

However that would miss

```
super duper 3333,and
```

So you would have to add "," or other puntuation to the list of trailing characters...

```
(?:^|\s)(\d{1,4})(?:\s|$|[,:;?])
```

However that brings us back to...

There were people numbering 5.  Today...

The 5 would get missed!  How do you tell the difference between that and "there were 55.55  percent of people"

Comment: it depends on the source data and if you are matching from paragraph text or from some sort of semi-structured data.

Comment: ^ is start of line $ is end of line because I want to match strings that contain **exclusively integer numbers between 0 and 9999*** if  any other char in string I want the string to not match at all